# Concatenating CSSs to style.css in H5BP

Tags: css, concatenation, html5boilerplate

I understand that H5BP build script (actually I'm using Node version btw) concatenates separated CSS files if putting `@import` in `style.css`.

Now I don't understand why the build script keeps imported (separated) CSS files in `publish` directory and why not remove them... They should be useless anymore! Additionally, I have to write `@import` right after the first line in `style.css` to load them properly, but `style.css` seems that something I should write my own styles after `primary styles` around line 217...

Can someone tell me what the best way to create website with separated CSSs and to concatenates them to `style.css` properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) to concatenate multiple css files easily.

Please see my build script at the following link which should give you what you want:

[How to concatenate and minify multiple CSS and JavaScript files with Grunt.js (0.3.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713273/how-to-concatenate-and-minify-multiple-css-and-javascript-files-with-grunt-js)