# Grunt gives a weird "WARN: ERROR: Unexpected token..." message

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm setting up grunt minification tasks for the following css file named "test.css":

```
body{
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: left;
}
```

I get the following message when I run `grunt`:

`WARN: ERROR: Unexpected token: punc ({) [test.css:1,4]`

My "Gruntfile.js" file currently looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  uglify: {
    options: {
      banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
    },
    min: {
      src: 'test.css',
      dest: 'test.min.css'
    }
  }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

My "package.json" file currently looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "kaidez",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.1.1"
  }
}
```

Running grunt v4.0 and node v0.8.20, both installed globally. Both `grunt-cli` and `uglify` are installed. "Gruntfile.js", "package.json" and "test.css" are in the same directory.  All of these files are in the "themes" directory for a WordPress site, but I don't that's the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `uglify` task is only for JavaScript files. For CSS, checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/13749226, which suggests [`grunt-css`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-css).

Comment: Jonathan Lonowski: Thanks much...it worked!!! If I code vote on comments, I would bump u up.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The uglify task is only for JavaScript files. For CSS, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713273/how-to-concatenate-and-minify-multiple-css-and-javascript-files-with-grunt-js/13749226#13749226), which suggests grunt-css (cit Jonathan Lonowski comment)

Comment: Argh, was banging my head against the wall for ages with this one.  So simple :)