# How to avoid lots of @import CSS but not work in one huge CSS file

Tags: html, css

I've noticed on a lot of my sites that I end up creating a folder called CSS and I put all my CSS files in there and than in the main CSS file I use the @import. I've read on numerous sites that using a lot of @imports is bad and when I do google speed test and other speed testers it says to avoid them.

```
@import "css/reset.css";
@import "css/utilities.css";
@import "css/menu.css";
@import "css/blog.css";
@import "css/author.css";
```

I was wondering how I can avoid this besides making one really big CSS file since it would take way to long to have to sort through and find what I need. Is there a way to have the server recompile them into one file each time I upload the individual CSS file? I'm updating and changing the CSS files often so merging them each time manually wouldn't be ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations for making an effort to keep your code well structured. If you are working on a static page you can have the cake and eat it to by developing with multiple files and later compiling them into one css file when you deploy your page. 
A tool that does that for static pages with no programming required is Hammer (http://hammerformac.com/) which is commercial and platform dependent. An open source toolchain would include something like Grunt ([How to concatenate and minify multiple CSS and JavaScript files with Grunt.js (0.3.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713273/how-to-concatenate-and-minify-multiple-css-and-javascript-files-with-grunt-js)) which would do the same thing but might be a little harder to set up in the first place.

Comment: I use wordpress for pretty much all my sites and design my own theme, will those work with wodpress?

Comment: Yes. You would create your theme as a static site, then compile the css and include it in your wordpress theme. i think wordpress defines standards on how themes should be constructed. Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to look into something like grunt. Now having this type of script on my server does it come at a cost? My goal is to speed up my page load times, does this grunt script have to run each time someone loads the site?

Comment: Usually you create your css/template locally and when you are ready to deploy it you compile the css with grunt and use the single file that has been created on your site so it does not have any performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is process your CSS server-side.  That way, you get all the benefit of keeping your CSS modular, while combining your common CSS into one file.

There are many ways to do this, from a simple Bash script to LESS and SASS.