# how to create Bundle.min.css of Css or Js file

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller

how to create Bundle.min.css in Mvc of Css or Js file. I Can not find the option Web essentials in ms Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can find what you are looking for by using Grunt. The below Stack Overflow link is a similar question including a previous solution. Below is also the Grunt website for some additional infromation.

[How to concatenate and minify multiple CSS and JavaScript files with Grunt.js (0.3.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713273/how-to-concatenate-and-minify-multiple-css-and-javascript-files-with-grunt-js-0)

http://gruntjs.com/

Comment: Is it possible in MVC 3

Comment: Your files are .JS and .CSS, right? All you do with Grunt is point to the location of you JS & CSS files (Can and should be different directories) and it does it's magic and produces the new file. It runs off a command prompt and once you start the process, it can run and watch for any changes to the files. Once you change a file (the original .JS or .CSS), it will regenerate the min file. You will then link to the min files and not the originals in your template(s).