# Make webpack bundle two .js files into one without encapsulation

Tags: javascript, webpack

I can't find this anywhere, and Im not sure webpack can actually do it.

I have an old .js file I wanna split into two .js files I want merged together. Not as modules but concatenated.

So 
hi.js

```
var yo = 'yo';
```

and hello.js

```
console.log(yo, 'hello');
```

becomes together.js

```
var yo = 'yo'; console.log(yo, 'hello');
```

The only way I can see it done now is by refactoring the code to support require or import.

My config:

```
    entry: {
    'plugin.js': [
        path.join(__dirname, 'keyboards.js'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'functionality.js')
    ]
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/fictional_codespace/'),
    filename: '[name]'
},
```

This only makes a plugin.js with two eval(), and then they cant see the variables

Comment: Have you tried, for example, webpack-concat-plugin? https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-concat-plugin

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471538/how-do-i-concatenate-and-minify-files-using-webpack

Comment: I was hoping this was a built in feature now