# require script files and then compiling them into 1

Tags: scripting, dependencies, require

I have a single HTML file in which I load a bunch of script files, like so:

> index.html

```
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-morris-chart/src/angular-morris-chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

I was wondering maybe there is a way to "require" all these in **one** script file like so:

> bower_components.js

```
require('bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js');
require('bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js');
etc ...
```

and later **in production**, compile `bower_components.js` to contain the actual scripts so that I could simply just use this:

```
 <script src="bower_components.js"></script>
```

Please note that I don't wish to run any sort of task in development environment. I don't want to compile my scripts when I work locally.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has already been answered, see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591854/using-gulp-to-concatenate-and-uglify-files

Comment: Maybe you should try Googling before asking. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713273/how-to-concatenate-and-minify-multiple-css-and-javascript-files-with-grunt-js-0

Comment: thanks, I already know what uglify is. It's not what I look for. read my post.

Comment: If you insist on using the `require` syntax, have a look at Browserify: http://browserify.org/ it will do what you are asking.